# Title vertical spacing using memoir

Tags: memoir

I would like to have the same vertical spacing among the titles lines...but for some reason it is different...

[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside,a5paper,extrafontsizes]{memoir} %Classe estilo memoir
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel} %Traduz doc para português do Brasil
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Reconhece acentuação
\usepackage{garamondx} %Define a nova fonte garamond


\title{Title of\\
     This Nice\\
      Book}
\author{John Doe }
\date{\today}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{% usado pra criar título personalizado

    \begin{center}
        {\Large\theauthor}\par
        \vspace*{\fill}
        {\Huge\textbf{\thetitle}}\par
        \vspace*{\fill}
        %\today
        %18ª Edição\\
        \vspace*{\fill}
        Florianópolis / SC\\
        % EDIPAPPI/LIPAPPI
    \end{center}
}

\chapterstyle{thatcher}

\begin{document} %======================================================================
\pagenumbering{gobble} %oculta numeração de página
\maketitle %título  

\end{document}
```

Is There a way to have the same space among the lines?

Comment: Probably need to place `\par` inside the group with Huge otherwise the line skip from the outside text is used. I'd also make the title page by hand via the titlingpage env inst ad of going through make title

Comment: @daleif `{\Huge\textbf{\thetitle} \par}` Thanks! Worked like a charm!

Comment: I am relatively new to LaTeX... make title seems to do the job for now.